# Run two Instances of OpenERP 8

Tags: odoo, openerp-8

I want to run two instances of OpenERP but once the first one is running I don't know why the second one access to the files of the first one, like `ir_http.py` from the first one. I noticed that it changes the directory, I did some debug on the files used with no luck because somehow the second instance manages to call the first one, trying to access their directory. This is my log:

```
    File "/home/user/lib/python2.7/Werkzeug-0.9.4-py2.7.egg/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 579, in __call__
return self.app(environ, start_response)
    File "/home/user/openerp-8.0-acmlpsc/openerp-8.0/openerp/http.py", line 1234, in dispatch
result = ir_http._dispatch()
    File "/home/user/openerp-8.0/openerp/addons_test/trunk-restaurant-addons/base/ir/ir_http.py", line 106, in _dispatch
werkzeug.exceptions.Forbidden))
    File "/home/user/openerp-8.0/openerp/addons_test/trunk-restaurant-addons/base/ir/ir_http.py", line 101, in _dispatch
auth_method = self._authenticate(func.routing["auth"])
    File "/home/user/openerp-8.0/openerp/addons_test/trunk-restaurant-addons/base/ir/ir_http.py", line 76, in _authenticate
request.session.check_security()
    File "/home/user/openerp-8.0-acmlpsc/openerp-8.0/openerp/http.py", line 801, in check_security
security.check(self.db, self.uid, self.password)
```

I can understand that the security check fails, because is the second instance trying to access the first one but why is the second one trying to access the first one! I don't get it.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you have two users (openerp-8.0-acmlpsc & openerp-8.0), one for each instance of OpenERP. That is correct!

Make sure that each of those users are the owners of each of their own directories (server, addons, etc)

Also make sure that each of those servers are using different configuration files. A lot of setups will put one `/etc/openerp-server.conf` and another in `/etc/openerp-server-test.conf`

They should be using different ports and own their own databases.